How to convert single column with XML data into multiple columns, while querying Extended Events XEL file
We have created an Extended Events session to capture errors with severity 16 or higher:
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Error_Reporting] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.session_server_principal_name,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([severity]>(15)))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/logs/Errors.xel',max_file_size=(10240), max_rollover_files=1)
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO

Now, we can query it by running:
select cast(event_data as xml), timestamp_utc
from sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/logs/Errors_0_133667581914690000.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)

Column event_data is nvarchar type but contains XML values, which represent a table.

Question:
How can be event_data column be converted (broken down) into multiple columns (such as UserName, Error_number, Category, Destination, Message and so on), when queried in text editor in SSMS ?
Example of XML data: https://pastecode.io/s/tjg7jo40

You should be able to use something like
SELECT 
        error_number = event_data_xml.value('(event/data[@name = "error_number"]/value/text())[1]', 'int'),
        username = event_data_xml.value('(event/action[@name = "username" and @package = "sqlserver"]/value/text())[1]', 'sysname'),
        xft.timestamp_utc
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/logs/Errors_0_133667581914690000.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL) xft
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(xft.event_data AS XML)) CA(event_data_xml)

So you use an XPath predicate to filter on the name attribute for the data/action elements of interest for each column (and additionally package attribute if needed).
For destination and category use /text/text() rather than /value/text() as the values are just map_keys in sys.dm_xe_map_values rather than anything meaningful outside of this context.
Also make sure that you filter on the correct element type for each column corresponding to the relevant parent element (above example has one each for data and action)

thanks @MartinSmith, everything works!  one last question (if I may) - "Destination" column, its value is stored as 0x00000002 in XML. Do you know what data type is that ? On the screenshot, value shows as "USER" (other possible values are "ERRORLOG" and something else), wonder how it converts it.  If you don't know, no problem, I will mark as answer in any case soon.
